how to make bars equal for dimension in ggplot
I have the following dataframe:
set.seed(123) # For reproducibility
df_long <- data.frame(
 trait = rep(c("Trait1", "Trait2", "Trait3", "Trait4", "Trait5"), each = 4), 
 type = rep(c("eur_ita", "eur_ita_2", "eur_ita_3", "eur_ita_4"), times = 5),   
 value = c(runif(5, 5, 15), runif(5, 8, 20), runif(5, 1, 12), runif(5, 4, 18)),
 macro_cat3 = rep(c("Category1", "Category2", "Category3"), each = 10) # Dividing into two macro categories
)

And I wrote the following code to have a bar plot:
ggplot(df_long, aes(x = trait, y = value, fill = type, alpha = type)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.6), color = "black", width = 0.6) +  # Adjust dodge and bar width
  facet_wrap(~ macro_cat3, scales = "free_x", ncol = 4) +  # Keep free_x scales
  labs(x = "Trait", y = "Percentage of r2", fill = " Type") +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c(
      "eur_ita" = "red",
  "eur_ita_2" = "black",
  "eur_ita_3" = "green",
  "eur_ita_4" = "gray"
    ),
    name = NULL  # Removes the legend title
  ) +
  scale_alpha_manual(
values = c(
  "eur_ita" = 1,
  "eur_ita_2" = 0.9,
  "eur_ita_3" = 0.9,
  "eur_ita_4" = 1
),
guide = "none") 

I created the following bar plot:

How can I modify the code so as to have equal bar width, regardless from the number of x values within each facet_wrap() panel? for example, here in the first panel, bars are bigger as there are only 2 observations over the x axis, while in the third panel bars are thinner as there are 8 x values. How to have equal bar width per each panel?

Change facet_wrap to facet_grid, remove the ncol = 4 and add the argument space = "free_x".

in this way the bars are too thin and the x axis is a mess of labels :( but thanks!!

The sample data and code you included doesn't produce the image you included in the question. (In fact, the data creation code causes an error). If you want multiple rows with bars the same width then there are also ways around this, but you should include that in your question, as well as some sample data that actually demonstrates the problem. As asked, your question is a duplicate, but it may not be if you need multiple rows.
